# COM CLSID CodeBase key

Tags: .net, com, com-interop, codebase, clsid

When .net assemblies are registered for COM Interop, there is a CodeBase key in the registry that points to the executable.

My question is: is the CodeBase key something specific to .NET, or is this a generic COM thing that all registered components are expected to have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx the CodeBase key is only relevant for .NET assemblies not present in the GAC.

Comment: That's part of my dilemma, its an ambiguous statement. Regasm is a .net tool, so you'd expect that documentation to be relevant only for .NET assemblies. This doesn't tell me whether CodeBase has any relevance outside of .NET.

Comment: OK this seems to better answer the question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908849.aspx